# My Angular home page is just showing a blank screen when I run the code with no errors

Tags: javascript, angular

This here is my code for I have tried everything can somebody please assist me

`home.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HomePage } from './home.page';

import { HomePageRoutingModule } from './home-routing.module';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    HomePageRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [HomePage]
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

`home.page.html`:

```
<ion-header [translucent]="true">
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>
          Arsenal Home Page
        </ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    
    <ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
      <ion-header collapse="condense">
        <ion-toolbar>
          <ion-title size="large">Arsenal Home Page</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
      </ion-header>
    
      <div id="container">
        <strong>Ready to create an app?</strong>
        <p>Start with Ionic <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://ionicframework.com/docs/components">UI Components</a></p>
    
        <button ion-button(click)="openLegendsPage()">Legends</button>
      </div>
    
    
    </ion-content>
```

I am trying to develop the app so if anybody may have an answer to this please let me know

Comment: You should share your app module and app component file also. It's not possible to understand your problem with above details.

Comment: app.module.ts. below

Comment: import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],entryComponents: [], imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],  providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }],  bootstrap: [AppComponent],})export class AppModule {}

Comment: app.component.ts-import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {}
}

Comment: You need to import `HomePageModule` in your `AppModule`, it's missing in import section

Comment: sorry whats the code that I put into the AppModule

Comment: Inside `imports` array of app module, add `HomePageModule`, so that the home route can be accessed.

Comment: Its telling me that the HomePageModule is declared but value never read do you know the code that comes where i put in import { HomePageModule } from '@angular/'; <-- this is what is giving me the red underline

Comment: I have imported my HomePageModule and it is still blank

Comment: Can you create a demo of your project in [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic)? It would be very helpful